# I need a Drupal workflow solution where I can edit live/published nodes and save without the edits going live until commited

Tags: 7, workflows

I need a module or method that can allow a PUBLISHED node to be edited in the admin and saved without the changes being made live until it is committed.

Site Example: http://bit.ly/p70f7E

```
1. User with EDIT permission logs in and edits this page/node - They make a copy edit such as changing the title "Litman Gregory Launches Alternative Strategies Fund" to "Litman Gregory Has Launched the Alternative Strategies Fund" or some kind of edit.
2. The user cannot publish the change but can save the revision or checkout/checking the file.
3. User with PUBLISH permission logs in and checks the edits for accuracy and then hits publish.
4. The page/node never gets unpublished, but the edits are made in the back-end without updating the live copy.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Workbench module](http://drupal.org/project/workbench). If I'm not mistaken you can make draft versions of nodes that have been published.

From the module page:

> Workbench provides overall improvements for managing content that
>   Drupal does not provide out of the box. Workbench gives us three
>   important solutions:
>
> a unified and simplified user interface for users who ONLY have to
>   work with content. This decreases training and support time. the
>   ability to control who has access to edit any content based on an
>   organization's structure not the web site structure a customizable
>   editorial workflow that integrates with the access control feature
>   described above or works independently on its own.

Comment: I recently implemented this module for a very similar use case and it worked great.

Comment: @donut a friendly remark: maybe "deployed" or "used" -- implemented a module means you coded the module and I suspect you didnt :)

Comment: Does Workbench module work with Blocks content as well?

Comment: I installed Revisioning Module - http://bit.ly/r2AGqR

It works great but only on pages/articles not blocks. On this site http://bit.ly/oGAeDz - everything under Funds & Performance uses Quicktabs modules which uses blocks. This Revisioning will work for now but any revisioning solutions for blocks?

Comment: Solved: http://bit.ly/nm5gep